# Create Point Feature with XY and Generate Multiple Buffers (ArcPy Tool)

Tags: arcpy, point, buffer, xy

I am trying to set up a custom tool via a python script in ArcMap. I want the tool to be able to create a point feature with X/Y input and then pass that point into the buffers.

My thinking is that someone could use the tool to find what is inside the radius from their given point that they input themselves without having to create a feature class first (I hope that makes it clearer).

Am I doing this right by creating the point feature and using the GetParameterAstext string? What exactly would go in the multiple ring buffer at the bottom?

```
import arcpy
import os

# Create a Point object from coordinates then set up buffer rings    
pnt.X = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
pnt.Y = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y) = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

BuffRing1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
BuffRing2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

distances = [BuffRing1, BuffRing2]
measure = ['miles']

arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis()
```

Answer (score 3):

- To understand what parameters go into any ArcPy command, the best resource is the Esri help pages (in this case, for [Multiple Ring Buffer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/multiple-ring-buffer.htm)). Parameters in curly brackets `{}` are optional. Any of these input parameters can either be hard-coded by you (for example, you might always want `Buffer_Unit` to be `"Miles"`), or passed in as variables that are set from user input parameters.

  ```
  arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(
      Input_Features,
      Output_Feature_class,
      Distances,
      {Buffer_Unit},
      {Field_Name},
      {Dissolve_Option},
      {Outside_Polygons_Only})
  ```
- You'll need to specify the `Output_Feature_class` since it is a required parameter of the tool. That can be either user-controlled, or hard-coded by you.
- An `arcpy.Point` can be created with just two numeric inputs ([ref.](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/point.htm))

  ```
  # Create point object
  input_x = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
  input_y = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
  point = arcpy.Point(input_x, input_y)
  ```
- And finally, the `measure` variable (presumably being passed in as the `Buffer_Unit`) should be a string, not a list.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to take this script and add it as a custom tool in a toolbox. I am not sure if I understand. I want it to open up in a dialog box so that I can add the x,y coordinates in their own rows and then have drop downs for the distance of my buffers. When I run the tool I want the point to generate based on the x,y with the buffers.

Comment: I understand that. What other parts of the process are you needing help with? Based on the two questions you asked above I thought this was all you needed, but I understand how complicated the Python tool creation process can be when you're doing it for the first time!

Comment: import arcpy
import os

XY = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
buffDist = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)


arcpy.Buffer_analysis(XY, outputFC, buffDist)

Comment: I am unable to get the tool to successfully run. It keeps saying that the tool failed.  When I go to set the parameters in the tool, I set XY = point, Output FC = feature class and BuffDist = linear unit. I tried to make this even more simple but it is not generating.

Comment: For BuffDist, you probably want numbers (float, integer) rather than linear unit.

Comment: It now says that it does not recognize any X Y coordinates that I input into the tool. "Execute Error: Failed to execute. Parameter not valid. ERROR0007322: Input features: Dataset (**any x/y I put) does not exist or is not supported.

Comment: It is probably looking for a layer or feature class, while you (I think) just want to type in an `x, y` pair -- refer to the `arcpy.Point` snippet above.

Comment: Okay, I get what you are saying now. What would the data type be for each coordinate in the script properties parameters?

Comment: As a parameter, just a number; it should get converted to an appropriate geometry type by the `arcpy.Point` object. (I have to say up front I'm only mostly sure this will work, since I've always used a feature class as an input, but _in theory_ I think using a geometry object as an input to the function is feasible. Fingers crossed.)

Comment: I can not find a number parameter. I looked at other geoprocessing tools that used coordinates and they all use the point parameter but I can not get my tool to recognize any input coordinates. Not sure where to go from here

Comment: By number I mean a float or integer. You should probably ask a new question about your problem with input parameters, as your script has now evolved a fair amount from your original questions :)