# Custom Script tool (ArcPy) Error: Input Features does not exist or is not supported

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

I am trying to create a custom tool that take x,y coordinates, buffers them and then puts them into a new feature class. Whenever I try to run the tool I get:

> ERROR000732 Input Features: Dataset (x, y coordinates) does not exist
>    or is not supported

Here is my script:

```
import arcpy
import os

point = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

outputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
buffDist = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(point, outputFC, buffDist)
```

Here is the error from the tool after the script is run:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Coordinates should be float. Could you try this ? Could you show your script ?

Comment: I have XY coordinates = Point, Output FC = Feature Class and BuffDist = Linear Unit.... Under data type in the parameter properties I do not see Float as an option. The only one that makes sense to me right now is Point.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256402/create-point-feature-with-xy-and-generate-multiple-buffers-arcpy-tool

Comment: Perhaps try with decimals.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve error messages we ask that you show us them in full using text rather than a picture so that they can be searched and also read easily on all devices.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and **`"`** and **`{}`** buttons that enables you to format any highlighted text nicely.

Comment: In my initial post I typed out the error message in full... {ERROR000732 Input Features: Dataset (x, y coordinates) does not exist or is not supported}

Answer (score 1):

According to its help page, the [`Buffer`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) operation requires a feature layer input. When an ArcPy error includes "does not exist or is not supported", and you're sure* the input exists, the remaining option is that it isn't the right type of input. In this case, you can't just pass two numbers -- `Buffer` was not programmed to be able to handle that.

You're going to need more code in your Python script to turn the point (x, y) into a Point geometry type, and possibly also turn it into a feature layer. I mentioned that in another answer, [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/256406/15768) (the bit about `arcpy.Point`).

---

* Being sure the input exists should include debugging with `print(point)` or `arcpy.AddMessage(point)` so your script shows you what it thinks the value of `point` is. Sometimes it's totally valid, sometimes it's not, and eliminating the easy possibilities saves time.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `GetParameterAsText`, it is literally a string. The input to [arcpy.Buffer_analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) requires, in your case, a [Point](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/point.htm). By converting the string input to a Point object, you should be able to get the tool to run:

```
point2 = point.split(" ")
point3 = arcpy.Point(float(point2[0]),float(point2[1]))
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(point3, outputFC, buffDist)
```

Now that I think of it, a quicker way would be to just use [`GetParameter`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/getparameter.htm) instead of `GetParameterAsText`. This will leave your point input as a Point object.